# Android communication with a USB device

Tags: android, usb, host

It's been a month that i try to connect my USB device, in mass storage to my tablett (Google Nexus 7).
I have read all the google documentation about [Android USB host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html), and i find nothing to read the file inside my USB device !

I have search trough differents forums, found few app doing USB viewer (Nexus media importer for exemple) but i haven't found any source code able to read files on an USB key, in mass storage.

I am now trying to implement the USB mass storage protocol, with the method

`bulkTransfer (UsbEndpoint endpoint, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout)`

But i don't know how to have the access to the device directories ...

Anyone has already solve this communication issue ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

Comment: i think connect a storage device is a Host Mode and not an Accessory Mode @Elior !

Comment: You do want host mode, meaning the tablet will supply the power to the device. Accessory mode would mean the device would supply the power to the tablet, and I don't think mass storage can supply power.

Comment: OK.. sorry I gave the wrong link.. But you can look at that site about host mode

Comment: That site is already in my favorites ! :) but my proplem is not to detect the usb device, it is to communicate with it, and obtain the files on it !

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you have the OTG cable that will tell the Nexus 7 to go into host mode? Secondly, you may want to read [this](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/29/3127278/nexus-7-mhl-usb-otg). The Nexus 7 supports USB Host mode for devices such as keyboards and mice, but does not support Host mode for storage devices.

Comment: Yes, i have bought an OTG cable ! And I have download the App _Nexus Media Importer_, who can scan my USB device
So it is possible to read, at less, files of storage device !

Comment: From my understanding the Nexus 7 (current generation) will not support storage devices at all, not matter if the Nexus is in host mode or not. The Galaxy Tab 2 7" does support full host mode, USB mass storage as well as other peripherials. I had done much research on these devices about two months ago and determined that for host mode the Galaxy Tab was the way to go, the Nexus just does not have FULL host mode support.

Comment: OK but i still don't understand how the App _Nexus Media Importer_ do, the app can read my usb device connected by the OTG cable on my Nexus 7 tablet ... :(

Comment: I can't tell you that, all I know is that seeminlgy for us that it does not seem that we will be able to leverage full usb host mode from the Nexus 7. I noticed that there is the limitation of read only for that app. Not sure if that is how they do it.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot @TronicZomB :)
I'll try to understand how they manage that communication, furthermore on an unroot Phone !

Comment: You're welcome. You could always try to contact the developer, they may help you, but unfortunately since they make the claim to the only app that allows non-rooting to get these features on the Nexus, I kind of doubt they will let you in on the secret...

Comment: @Manu, FYI and for those who may concern, according to [USB Host Diagnostics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics&hl=en) app, Nexus 7 does fully support USB Host mode.

Answer (score 0):

Does the root of the external storage show when you run the method below?

```
Context.getExternalMediaDirs()
```

If so, you should be able to just open the file, using the path returned.